# How to check input text to compare its value to a sibling element images attribute 'name', when a dynamic button is clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I'm relatively new to jquery, I've been working on a game in my spare time, anyways I'm working on a section where a user can try to guess the name of an image in an input field and what I'm trying to accomplish is when a button element(that was previously created) is clicked, if the user guesses right it will alert the user they are correct and if not, tell them obviously they are WRONG!

This is the code.. (I have right now and when i inspect my page my console isn't even registering that my button on click is being called???)

```
//This is my code that creates the section I'm working with dynamically
 $('#guessImageContainer').append('<li><img id="favoriteImage" src="' + 
 highestRating.prev('img').attr('src') + '" name="' + 
 highestRating.prev('img').attr('name') + '"><input id="guessMyValue" 
 type="text"><button class="text-center" id="finishButton">Finish 
 Button</button><h2 class="text-center">Now Guess The Name Of Your 
 Favorite Image</h2></li>');

 //This is my code i would assume would check the users input
 $('#finishButton').on('click', function (){
  console.log("finish button clicked");
  let userGuessInput = $('#guessMyValue').val;
  $('#fifth-rule').removeClass('hidden');
  $('#resultContainer').removeClass('hidden');
  if (userGuessInput === $('#favoriteImage').attr('name')){

      $('#resultText').append("You GUESSED RIGHT!! Imgae=" + 
  $('#favoriteImage').attr('name'))
  }
  else if (userGuessInput != $('#favoriteImage').attr('name')){

      $('#resultText').append("Unfortunately your WRONG!!! Imgae=" + 
  $('#favoriteImage').attr('name'))
  }
  });

  //This is the code in my html where I want to alert the result of the 
  users guess(#resultText)
   <div id="resultContainer" class="hidden col-md-4 offset-md-3">
      <p id="resultText"></p>
   </div>
```

[image: game section]

This is the whole gameboard

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Since the button isn't created until later in your application, you need to ensure that you are registering the event listener for the finish button once the button itself has been created.  In other words, ensure that you are registering the button's event listener **after** you append it to the document.  I achieved this by creating a function that creates the event listener, and called that function right after the button was created, like so:

```
$('#guessCheck').on('click', function () {
    //
    // chose the right inputs
    //
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    let highestRating = $('#checkedImageContainer input[type=number]').map(function () {
      return {ele: $(this), val: parseFloat(this.value)};
    }).get().sort(function (a, b) {
      return b.val - a.val;
    })[0].ele;
    $('#fourth-rule').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#guessImageContainer').removeClass('hidden');
    console.log('removed hidden class on the #highestrated list');
    $('#guessImageContainer').append('<li><img id="favoriteImage" src="' + highestRating.prev('img').attr('src') + '" name="' + highestRating.prev('img').attr('name') + '"><input id="guessMyValue" type="text"><button class="text-center" id="finishButton">Finish Button</button><h2 class="text-center">Now Guess The Name Of Your Favorite Image</h2></li>');
    registerFinishButtonListener();
  });

function registerFinishButtonListener() {
  $('#finishButton').on('click', function (){
      console.log("finish button clicked");
      let userGuessInput = $('#guessMyValue').val();
      $('#fifth-rule').removeClass('hidden');
      $('#resultContainer').removeClass('hidden');
      if (userGuessInput === $('#favoriteImage').attr('name')){

          $('#resultText').append("You GUESSED RIGHT!! Imgae=" + $('#favoriteImage').attr('name'))
      }
      else if (userGuessInput != $('#favoriteImage').attr('name')){

          $('#resultText').append("Unfortunately your WRONG!!! Imgae=" + $('#favoriteImage').attr('name'))
      }
  });

}
```

Let me know if this does the trick for you!

**ALSO**
It appears as though you were assigning a new ID to all `<p>` elements that are a child of a `<div>`, which basically removed your ID for the answer area, and made it so that we were not able to append the answer text to the `<p>` element.  Modify the guess `confirmedAge()` function to this:

```
function confirmedAge(){
    let userAge = $('#usersInput').val();
    console.log(userAge);
    if (userAge <= 1999){
        $('#gameRules').removeClass('hidden');
        console.log("hidden class removed");
        $('#ageID').hide()

        let userAgesLog =[];
        userAgesLog.push(userAge);
        console.log("highlighted")
    }
    else  if (userAge >= 2000){
        alert("You are of not of the age requirement to play this game")

    }
};
```

**ADDITIONALLY,**

In order to get the value of a text input via jQuery, you need to call the value method using .val().  You called it incorrectly in your finish button event listener, by forgetting the parentheses.  `.val()` is a method, not a property.  Modify the registerFinishButton function to look like this:

function registerFinishButtonListener() {

```
  $('#finishButton').on('click', function (){
      console.log("finish button clicked");
      let userGuessInput = $('#guessMyValue').val();
      $('#fifth-rule').removeClass('hidden');
      $('#resultContainer').removeClass('hidden');
      if (userGuessInput === $('#favoriteImage').attr('name')){

          $('#resultText').append("You GUESSED RIGHT!! Imgae=" + $('#favoriteImage').attr('name'))
      }
      else if (userGuessInput != $('#favoriteImage').attr('name')){

          $('#resultText').append("Unfortunately your WRONG!!! Imgae=" + $('#favoriteImage').attr('name'))
      }
  });
```

Comment: I already have it enclosed inside a document.ready good thought tho, I tried attaching my whole jquery code into a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kx6saz02/

Comment: @Max  would it be too much to ask to have the HTML added to that fiddle?  I'll be able to get a better idea of what's going on from there. :)

Comment: I should of did that from the getco my appologies... I added the css too... because my code is using boostrap styling, I had the same issue previously that my code won't run sometimes in jsfiddle... but heres the update https://jsfiddle.net/efxxtas4/

Comment: Hey @Max, I figured out the solution and modified my answer to reflect it.  Let me know how it works.

Comment: hey @Alexender_Edwards, i tried your code out, the only difference i noticed is...  #resultContainer becomes visible along with the #fufth-rule, however I'm not noticing any of my code being appended to my p element inside of the #resultContainer, were you able to append the ^^^text according to the input val?

Comment: @Max and if all works, please mark me as the answer and throw me an upvote, I will do the same for you :)

Comment: @Max Did it work?  Please mark my answer as the answer and upvote my answer if you can, since I helped you solve this. :)

Comment: So I was able to append into the p element,but it wan;t what i was hoping for... its appending the wrong output still, any suggestions?  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn6cN.png

Comment: Hey man i definetly will throw you an upvote, I just gotta go to work, I'll check it out when i get home, thats cool?